# Sum of a number with any k elements in Array

Tags: algorithm, subset, subset-sum

> Design an algorithm that, given a set S of n integers and another
>   integer x, determines whether or not there exist k (n>k>2) elements in
>   S whose sum is exactly x. Please give the running time of your
>   algorithm

I have been preparing for an interview, and i have come across this algorithm. I have solved problems where k has been specified in the problem.  like 2 or 3. But i cannot find an answer where i might solve  for any k that might exist. I have tried solving it using dynamic programming but didn't get results. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Are integers from the set S positive, or can they be also negative?

Comment: Does this article solve your problem? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/

Answer (score 3):

You can make an `int` array `cnt` of size `x`, then go through the set, and mark reachable points. All elements of `cnt` are set to `-1` initially except element zero, which is set to zero.

Repeat the same process for each element `si` of `S`: for each element of `cnt` at position `i` that is non-negative, check element `cnt[i+si]` (if it's within the bounds of the array). If it is, set it to `cnt[si+i] = max(cnt[i]+1, cnt[si+i])`.

Once you go through all elements of `S`, check `cnt[x]`. If it is set to two or more, then there exists a combination of two or more elements in `S` adding up to `x`.

This algorithm is pseudo-polynomial, with running time `O(x*|S|)`